# Cannot display facebook app in a frame

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing an app for facebook with php . But I've stacked on blank page on facebook when I try to run the app . The error message that I get from console is :

Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Any help appretiated

PS . my question was reported as a duplicate but none from the suggested solutions applied to my issue . Also all the solutions are not for facebook but for youtube , vimeo , etc..

Comment: Why do you need to have it in a frame?

Comment: Hello it is not a duplicate as this question is specific to facebook app . @DipenShah

Comment: If it is your app that is sending that header, then you have to configure it to not do that. In that case, this is not Facebook-specific at all – you would have the same problem trying to display your app’s URL in any (i)frame on any other domain as well.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook prevents their pages from being loaded in an iframe.

If you're sending the user to a Facebook URL (for example, the authentication or feed dialogs), do it in a new window, or use `target="_top"` to open it outside the iframe.